# Why does mailutils depend on mariadb-common and mysql-common and what are *-common packages in the first place?

Tags: debian, apt

I was about to install `mailutils` and `postfix` when I notice how many dependencies were involved.

```
$ apt install mailutils postfix
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  guile-2.2-libs libgc1c2 libgsasl7 libkyotocabinet16v5 libltdl7 liblzo2-2 libmailutils5 libmariadb3 libntlm0 libpython2.7 mailutils-common
  mariadb-common mysql-common ssl-cert
```

Why does `mailutils` depend on `mariadb-common` and `mysql-common` and what are `*-common` packages in the first place?

I am trying to install a SMTP server that will run localhost-only and wish to be able to send emails using the `mail` command installing as few dependencies as possible.

Answer (score 2):

postfix has lots of features.  Dependency chain: postfix, postfix-mysql, libmariadbclient18, mysql-common.

To skip optional dependencies, use [`apt-get --no-install-recommends`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179060/how-to-not-install-recommended-and-suggested-packages).

As to what "common" packages, are from [mysql-common description](https://packages.debian.org/buster/mysql-common):

> This package includes files needed by all versions of the client
> library, e.g. /etc/mysql/my.cnf.

Extrapolating a bit, common packages contain files used by most users of a thing. They might be shared libraries containing common code, where a server and a client package can be installed separately. Or, shared config files used by all versions of a thing.

Comment: Thanks John! About "common" packages... what I don't understand in the context of Postfix is that "mysql-server" is not depended upon... so why would we need "mysql-common"?

Comment: Also, about `--no-install-recommends`, do you mean apt installs them by default? I searched around and apparently it does... I was under the impression that they were... recommended... as in optional.

Comment: How `postfix-mysql` was supposedly automatically added when it is merely suggested I don't know.  Check your configuration for `APT::Install-Suggests`  Should you really be after "as few dependencies as possible", you need to be able to trace dependency chains and figure out if they are necessary.